# WordPress/Gutenberg - Open panels after editor is loaded

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to open panels after editor loading. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I use the `domReady` function to wait the full loading of my page.

`domReady` function isn't that supposed to wait for the whole page to load?

I wrote my code in a plugin.

In index.js :

```
wp.domReady(() => {
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelOpened( 'featured-image' );
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelOpened( 'taxonomy-panel-keywords' );
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelOpened( 'taxonomy-panel-teachers' );
});
```

And in my PHP file I used `wp-editor` to enqueue my script.

```
function ccn_load_editor_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-ccn-gutenberg-editor', plugins_url('ccn-gutenberg-editor/build/index.js'), array( 'wp-data', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ), wp_rand(), true);
}

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'ccn_load_editor_script' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `window.onload` to accomplish this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelOpened( 'featured-image' );
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelOpened( 'taxonomy-panel-keywords' );
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelOpened( 'taxonomy-panel-teachers' );

};
```

`onload` is later than `domReady` as it is only executed after all content is loaded.

Comment: This actually helped me with toggling `yoast-seo/document-panel`. Thanks!